# How is an open file table implemented in Linux?

Tags: linux

In order to store variable amount of file handles the table-size has to grow and shrink a lot. I can think of 2 approaches here:

- Either have something like a c++ vector to implement it, so that it grows dynamically
- Or have a static array with a high capacity that ensures you never run out of places to store file handles.

I know its a classic static vs dynamic array problem, but at an OS level where performance and space is so important, I just want to know how do the brilliant minds behind linux solve this?

Comment: Linux is open source, and there are also books that explain the design. Use these resources to learn. This is not something that affects application programmers.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178383/how-is-the-open-file-table-structured

Comment: thank you @Barmar for the link. But I would respectfully not agree to the idea that if books are written on a topic then we should not ask questions. You are probably very senior in this community but for someone new, it doesn't feel welcoming.

Comment: OK, then ask in the appropriate place. This is not the site for questions about the design of Linux, [linux.se] is. [so] is for practical programming questions.

Comment: I believe the answer is that it's just a fixed-size array, whose size is specified at system configuration time.